# Remove a sub list from nested list based on an element in Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
 l = [["a", "done"], ["c", "not done"]]
```

If the second element of each sub list is "done" I want to remove that the sub list.
So the output should be:

```
l = [["c", "not done"]]
```

Obviously the below doesn't work:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i][1] == "done":
        l.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `list_comprehension`. It just builts a new list by iterating over the sublists where the second element in each sublist won't contain the string `done`

```
>>> l = [["a", "done"], ["c", "not done"]]
>>> [subl for subl in l if subl[1] != 'done']
[['c', 'not done']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [["a", "done"], ["c", "not done"]]
print [i for i in l if i[1]!="done"]
```

or use `filter`

```
l = [["a", "done"], ["c", "not done"]]
print filter(lambda x:x[1]!="done",l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter for your criteria:

```
l = [["a", "done"], ["c", "not done"]]
l = filter(lambda x: len(x)>=2 and x[1]!='done', l)
```

Answer (score 0):

> status index is 1, you checked index 0

```
for i in range(len(l)):
       if(l[i][1] == "done"):
           l.pop(i)
```

Comment: its better to include a little explanation in your answer

Comment: I corrected the answer...But the for loop in range will not work because you will get an index out of range error

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
l = [ item for item in l if item[-1] != 'done']
```